# C# Application as Web Application

Tags: c#, web-applications

Can a regular C# application run as a web application?

What I mean exactly is can compile in a way that my regular application become a web app that accept query string?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is this “regular application” you're talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend building your logic into a [Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d11h6832%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  You can then make a simple shell for a regular application, or use this from a Web application to call into your logic.

This will provide a clean, reusable method of handling both scenarios easily.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "regular C# application",  you probably mean a forms-based application.

The answer is "no", as the technologies are totally different.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if a winform application can be run as a web app then No.

If you are asking if its possible to build an app that runs on the desktop and the web then that is possible with Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Create a WCF contract, you can run your ""Regular app"" as a web app by writing a few more lines of code. For a head start look at :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119(v=vs.90).aspx